# Connection fail when WCF Concurrency Mode set to multiple

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, c#-4.0, concurrency

I am working on WCF. I want concurrency type multiple, mean multiple thread on each request. I have set parameters on methods that are define in Service class implementation and prototype define in interface. I'm using following parameters on service as below

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple,
    InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall,
    ReleaseServiceInstanceOnTransactionComplete = false,
    TransactionIsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)]
    public class BusinessPartnerService : IBusinessPartnerService
```

Now when I call any method on my service from one service to another then an exception is thrown:

> The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server.

Am I missing some configuration or something else? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you you using some tool like SoapUI? It might depend on client configuration only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ConcurrencyMode.Multiple` and `InstanceContextMode.PerCall` makes **no sense** together.

The `InstanceContextMode.PerCall` means that each and every single request will get its **own instance** of the service class to handle the request - therefore, `ConcurrencyMode.Multiple` is totally pointless since each request has its own instance of the service class anyway.

There's **no** possibility of multiple threads/request wanting to use the same service class instance anyway - each one has its own instance.

The preferred way of doing things in WCF would be `InstanceContextMode.PerCall` (each request gets its own, separate instance of the service class to handle its job) combined with `ConcurrencyMode.Single` (since each service class instance will only ever handle a single request anyway!)

`ConcurrencyMode.Multiple` would only ever make sense if you had a singleton service class (`InstanceContextMode.Single`) that would need to handle multiple requests concurrently. This however then poses a lot of extra effort on your side - the implementation of that service class singleton must be 100% threadsafe - not an easy task to do!

Comment: and what about InstanceContextMode.PerSession. What happen is that case? Is It'll not work fine in that case?

Comment: @NomiAli: per-session means: the first call gets a brand-new instance of the service class, and every subsequent call will get the same instance - but again: **each** request has **its own instance** of the service class - absolutely no need for `ConcurrencyMode.Multiple`!

Comment: Its mean If I want to achieve concurrency against multiple services with different threads working concurrently I need to use Single InstanceContextMode and code against it?

Comment: any helpful link will be very appreciated.

Comment: bro it's confusing, You said the prefer way is PerCall and concurrency mode single. In percall, every request create its own seperate instance of the service class and single concurrency mode will never be in action as every request get its own service object. Now if request come for another client, will the concurrency achieve? why we not use PerSession with multiple concurrency as each client get it's session that will handle all requests of the same client. and what if another client make a request to service.?

Comment: @NomiAli: yes - every request gets its own instance of the service class to handle the request. And yes, there can be multiple requests serviced at the same time - each with its own class instance.